# How to column(duplicated) to row header

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm using pandas to deal one csv file, i want convert a duplicated column to row header, but it said can't reshape?

I tried with df.piovt(), pd.pivot_table(), I failed.

```
    station_id      dut_id  ...    item_name  measured_value
0            d  q910296T0l  ...         H_bT              88
1            d  q910296T0l  ...        H_2V0             721
2            d  q910296T0l  ...   H_2V0_PERI              11
3            d  q910296T0l  ...       H_VDDR             973
4            d  q910296T0l  ...           fd               y
..         ...         ...  ...          ...             ...
915          d  q910296T0l  ...  k_ASSISTANT               y
916          d  q910296T0l  ...     k_VOL_UP               y
917          d  q910296T0l  ...   k_VOL_DOWN               y
918          d  q910296T0l  ...      k_INPUT               y
919          d  q910296T0l  ...      DUT_DSN           12345
```

in item_name column, it's duplicated,but i expect the output as below:

```
dut_id      H_bT   H_2v0  H_2V0_PERI H_VDDR   fd   ... DUT_DSN
q910296T0l  88     721    11          973     y    ... 12345
q910296T02  88     722    22          975     y    ... 12345
...
```

total 20 rows

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to manually change the `dut_id` column first:

```
df["dut_id"] = df["dut_id"] + df.index.astype(str)   # Add a new number to each dut_id
```

Then perform the pivot:

```
df.pivot(index="dut_id", columns="item_name", values="measured_value")
```